# Using FluentValidator to validate children of properties

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I want to use FluentValidation to validate some classes one of which is only used as a property on another... but I never directly create the child class so I want to test validation from the parent level. This may be unnecessary / crazy

So for example I have

```
public class Parent
{
  public string Text {get;set;}
  public Child Child {get;set;}
}

public class Child 
{
  public string Text {get;set;}
}
```

and

```
public class ParentValidator : AbstractValidator<Parent>
{
  public ParentValidator() 
  {
    RuleFor(p=>p.Text).NotEmpty();
  //RuleFor(p=>p.Child).SetValidator(new ChildValidator);
  //RuleFor(p=>p.Child.Text).NotEmpty();
  }
}

public class ChildValidator : AbstractValidator<Child>
{
  public ChildValidator() 
  {
    RuleFor(c=>c.Text).NotEmpty();
  }
}
```

which I test using

```
    [Test]
    public void ParentMustHaveText()
    {
        new ParentValidator()
             .ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(p => p.Text, "");
    }
    [Test]
    public void ChildMustHaveText()
    {
        new ParentValidator().ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(p => p.Child.Text, "");
    }
```

The `ChildMustHaveText` test always fails no matter how I set things up. Am I being crazy trying to test it that way?

since the following test always passes

```
    [Test]
    public void ChildMustHaveText()
    {
        new ChildValidator().ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(c => c.Text, "");
    }
```

The classes are models in an ASP.NET WebApi Project.

Comment: I don't want to look as dumb, but your rule definitions for child property are both commented.

Comment: Yep, that might not be clear. No matter what combination I set that up with I couldn't make the test pass. I just gave up in the end

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first error is that you forget to specify creation of `Child` property object in default `Parent` constructor — FluentValidation try to set dynanically property of `null`.

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        Child = new Child();
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that default constructor always uses in `ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor` for object creation before validation.

The next thing I found is that **current implementation of** `ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor` **doesn't allow to check validity of nested properties with nesting level more than 1** (`obj.Child1.Child2.Text` is level 3 of nesting, for example).

***PITFALL***

Source code of buggy place (`FluentValidation.TestHelper.ValidatorTester` class):

```
public void ValidateError(T instanceToValidate) {
        accessor.Set(instanceToValidate, value);
        // 
        var count = validator.Validate(instanceToValidate, ruleSet: ruleSet).Errors.Count(x => x.PropertyName == accessor.Member.Name);

        if (count == 0) {
            throw new ValidationTestException(string.Format("Expected a validation error for property {0}", accessor.Member.Name));
        }
    }
```

***EXPLANATION***

Method compares joined property names with validation errors (`x.PropertyName`) with property object `System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo` name (`accessor.Member.Name`), e.g. `"Text"` and `"Child.Text"` with `"Text"` **for both tests**, so test pass only because of `parent.Text` is null, it's not valid and property names equal to each other in both classes.

If simplify — now your test passes, but by wrong reason.

You can see this strange behavior if you rename one of string property:

```
public class Child 
{
    public string Text2 {get;set;}
}
```

or if you make `Parent.Text` property valid in tests (remove rule, or initialize in `Parent()` default constructor by not empty value).

```
public Parent()
{
    Child = new Child();
    Text = "I like pitfalls";
}
```

***CONCLUSION***

It's a bug in TestHelper class, and I hope this research helps you to decide on future test strategy for your application.

And never give up! ;-)