# FluentValidation ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor with SetCollectionValidator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I'm using the FluentValidation library in an ASP.NET MVC project and, from a UI perspective, it's working as expected. Rule violations display the correct errors.

I have a parent class that has a validator and a collection property where that type has a validator. It's conceptually the same as described in the [documentation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CreatingAValidator&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#Collections).

I have a validator for a parent class...

```
public class MyFormValidator : AbstractValidator<MyFormViewModel>
```

...and I have a collection in `MyFormViewModel`...

```
public IList<ChildRow> ChildRowsAdded { get; set; }
```

...and I create a validator for the collection of that child class...

```
public class ChildRowValidator : AbstractValidator<ChildRow>
```

...and I use that child validator in the parent validator...

```
RuleFor(m => m.ChildRowsAdded).SetCollectionValidator(new ChildRowValidator());
```

While writing some unit tests, I noticed that `ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor` is not confirming the errors exist.

```
_validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.ChildRowsAdded, model);
```

That line in my test does not seem to see the errors. The test fails and the message says

> FluentValidation.TestHelper.ValidationTestException : Expected a
>   validation error for property AllergyRowsAdded.

If I manually `.Validate()` and look at the results, I see the error.

Has anyone run into this before? Is there an additional step I need to take to use `ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor` in this situation?

Comment: I thought that you can use `validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(m => m.Childs[0].Name, model);` but it doesn't work either. When I looked into FluentValidation source codes it seems that it is not possible to use `ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor` assert for this type of test.

Comment: For anyone interested, I cross-posted this on the project's discussion board and got more detail there. http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/580454#post1351410

Answer (score 8):

According to [the docs](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/testing.html), there is another way to test nested properties: a string name that represents the path to the nested property:

> ```
> // You can also use a string name for properties that can't be easily represented with a lambda, eg:
> result.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor("Addresses[0].Line1");
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Jookin is absolutely right in his comment:

`ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor` method doesn't designed to validate properties of properties, you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29481459/571203).

There are 2 solutions:

1. Use `ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor` and test `ChildRowValidator` directly, like this: `_childValidator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.Name, childModel); 
   // direct descendant property can be validated`
2. Avoid this helper method and use `Assert` class to check, if in `ValidationResult` object exists any error with name, that match your array item(s) property by regexp or simple string comparison.

Choose one, that much more meet your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Now, we can do it like that:

in child validator:

```
RuleForEach(request => request.ChildRowsAdded)
                .SetValidator(new ChildRowValidator())
                .When(request => request.ChildRowsAdded != null); // whatever your rule
```

And

```
 var result = _validator.TestValidate(model);
 result.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.ChildRowsAdded);
```